# Como puedo obtener la posición de un elemento en una lista C++

Tags: c++, nodos

Tengo una lista en c++ y necesito saber la posición de cada elemento, para poder eliminar los elemento de la lista en el orden que quiera

```
bool Lista::Eliminar(int indice)
{
Aquí el código para eliminar el elemento en la posición (índice)
}
```

El método que llama la función eliminar es este:

```
void Eliminar()
{
    int indice = 0;
    Listar();
    cout << "Elija el artículo a eliminar => ";
    cin >> indice;   // Aqui el valor int que se refiere al elemento quiero eliminar
    lista->Eliminar(indice - 1); 
    cout << endl;
    Listar();
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se guardan los elementos de la lista? ¿Es una lista enlazada? De ser así ¿Es simple o doblemente enlazada?

Comment: Lo que buscas son estructuras de datos, en específico una lista enlazada como ya comentaron, aquí hay un link bien explicado, espero te sirva http://conclase.net/c/edd/cap1 tiene un apartado para eliminar un nodo y demás operaciones

Answer (score 0):

¡¡Asumiendo que es una lista ligada sencilla!!

Hay 3 cosas a considerar para eliminar un NODO de una lista:

1. El indice a eliminar es valido, es decir, no es un numero negativo o el indice no es
   mayor al numero de NODOS?
2. El indice a eliminar es el primero, es decir, es el primer NODO de la lista?
3. El indice a eliminar es diferente al primero de la lista?

Tomando estas consideraciones, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Si es el primero NODO, debes ayudarte de otro puntero para recorrer el primer NODO al segundo, ya que el primero sera eliminado.

Si es cualquier otro NODO, debes ayudarte de dos punteros, uno que sera el nodo a eliminar, y otro que sera uno previo al que elimines, para que este se enlace al siguiente NODO.

Espero te sirva mi info, te dejo el codigo que hice para que entiendas mejor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Nodo {
    public:
    int dato;
    Nodo *next;
};

class ListaLigada {
    private:
    Nodo *first;

    public:
    ListaLigada(int *, int);
    void imprimir();
    int eliminar(int);
};

ListaLigada::ListaLigada(int *elementos, int longitud) {
    Nodo *final;
    Nodo *temporal;

    first = new Nodo;
    first->dato = elementos[0];
    first->next = NULL;
    final = first;

    for(int i = 1; i < longitud; i++) {
        temporal = new Nodo;
        temporal->dato = elementos[i];
        temporal->next = NULL;
        final->next = temporal;
        final = temporal;
    }
}

void ListaLigada::imprimir() {
    Nodo *lista = first;
    while(lista != NULL) {
        cout << lista->dato << " ";
        lista = lista->next;
    }
}

int ListaLigada::eliminar(int indice) {
    Nodo *temporal = first;
    Nodo *previo;
    int valor = -1;

    //Si el indice a eliminar es el primero
    if(indice == 1) {
        valor = first->dato;
        first = first->next;
        delete temporal;
        return valor;
    }
    //Si el nodo a eliminar es diferente del primero
    else {
        //For para buscar el Nodo que sera eliminado
        for(int i = 0; i < indice - 1; i++) {
            previo = temporal;
            temporal = temporal->next; //al final, el puntero llamado temporal, contendra el nodo a eliminar
        }
        previo->next = temporal->next; //previo se enlaza al nodo que apunta temporal, desenlazamos el nodo a eliminar
        valor = temporal->dato;
        delete temporal;
        return valor;
    }
}

int main() {
    int elementos[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
    ListaLigada lista(&elementos[0], 5);
    lista.imprimir();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Valor eliminado: " << lista.eliminar(4) << endl;
    lista.imprimir();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si esta solución te sea de ayuda pero por lo que entiendo de tu pregunta es que necesitas saber cómo eliminar un elemento de una lista dado su índice, para esto yo suelo usar el vector de la STL de C++ de esta manera...

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
vector <int> V; //declaramos una lista o arreglo dinámico
for(int i=1;i<=3;i++){
    cin>>n;
    V.push_back(n); // guardamos los elementos
}

cin>>index;

V.erase(V.begin() + index); //eliminamos el elemnto que se pide

for(int i=0;i<V.size();i++){
    cout<<V[i]<<" "; //imprimiendo los elementos actuales
}

return 0;
```

}